# In Android Studio, how can I change the colour of the effect that appears at the end of a Scroll View?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I change the colour of the effect that appears at the end of a Scroll View?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYFT.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView#setBottomEdgeEffectColor(int)

something like

```
scrollview.setBottomEdgeEffectColor(0xFF4CAF50);
```

Comment: @ErdemGunseli by the way that colour is also linked to one of the values in /res/values/styles.xml it might be colorControlHighlight or colorAccent.

Comment: Yes, I think it is android:colorEdgeEffect.